# An inverse question of uniformly convergence

Tags: analysis, functions, uniform-convergence

{Edit: since I made some mistake on the pointwise limit and the uniformly continuous.}

A classical results in elementary analysis state that if a sequence of continuous function $f_n(x)$ on $[0,1]$ is uniformly convergence to $f$, then $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ too.

I am wondering that if we know that $f$ is continuous on  $[0,1]$, and it is a pointwise limit of a sequence of continuous function $f_n$ on $[0,1]$, can we conclude that $f_n$ convergence to $f$ uniformly on $[0,1]$?

I have noted that if $f$ is not continuous, then there has a counter example, $f_n=x^n$, $f(1)=1$ and $f=0$ otherwise. But how about add the continuous to $f$?

Comment: No. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500399/a-theorem-about-converge-pointwisely-and-uniformly) for an extreme example.

Comment: Your first paragraph is wrong. The pointwise limit of a sequence of continuous functions need not be continuous.

Comment: For a less extreme example consider the functions $f_n$, where the graph of $f_n$ consists of the straight line segments connecting the points $(0,0)$, $(1/n,1)$, $(2/n,0)$,   and $(1,0)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks, I made some mistake on uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For example, consider the functions $f_n$ on $[0,1]$, where the graph of $f_n$ consists of the straight line segments connecting the points $(0,0)$, $(1/(n+1),1)$, $(1/n,0)$,   and $(1,0)$. The sequence of continuous functions $(f_n)$ converges pointwise to the zero function on $[0,1]$; but, the convergence is not uniform.

More interesting, is that a pointwise convergent  sequence of continuous functions to a continuous limit need not converge uniformly on any open subset of $[0,1]$. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500399/a-theorem-about-converge-pointwisely-and-uniformly) for counterexamples.