# Suppose each $f_n$ is continuous on $S$ and that $f=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f_n$ is also continuous on $S$. Does $f_n$ converge uniformly on $S$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Suppose each $f_n$ is continuous on $S$ and that $f=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f_n$ is also continuous on $S$. Does this imply that $f_n$ converges uniformly on $S$?

I know that the uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous. However, is the converse true?

Comment: Consider a function whose graph is a triangular spike with tip at $(1/n,1)$ and "base" on the interval $[0,2/n]$.

Comment: What about $f_n(x) = \frac{x}{n}$ on $\Bbb R$?

Comment: See [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500399/a-theorem-about-converge-pointwisely-and-uniformly), also.

Comment: @DavidMitra think I saw a similar function when looking at a theorem about integrals. What is the connection, if there is one?

Comment: You can use those to construct  a sequence of continuous functions on $[0,1]$, say, that converge to a continuous function (the zero function), but not uniformly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No and for the counter example let $f_n(x)=x^n, \; x\in[0,1)$ we have $f_n$ doesn't converge uniformly to the zero function since $||f_n||_\infty=1$.

Comment: I think I will add more to this, just in case it is helpful down the line. I think the reason why Sami Ben Romdhane says that $\vert\vert f_n\vert\vert_{\infty}=1$ proves that $f_n$ doesn't converge uniformly to $f$ is because of a theorem/remark. According to the remark/theorem, a sequence $(f_n)$ of functions on a set $S$ converges uniformly to a function $f$ on $S$ if and only if $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sup\{\vert f(x)-f_n(x)\vert :x\in S\}=0$$

Comment: Here, $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sup\{\vert f(x)-f_n(x)\vert :x\in S\}=0$$ 

Substituting $f(x)=0$ and we are left with $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\{\vert f_n\vert :x\in S\vert\}=1\neq 0$