# Uniform convergence on compact sets

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

If I have a sequence of functions $(f_n)$ that converges to a function $f$ that is continuous (and therefore uniformly continuous on compact sets) can I then say that $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $f$ on compact sets?

I only know that, if the $f_n$ are continuous and convergent uniformly to $f$ that then $f$ is continuous, too.

Comment: No. Take $f_n(x)=1$ for $0<x<1/n$;  $f(x)=0$ otherwise. Then $(f_n)$ converges non-uniformly to the zero function on $[0,1]$.

Comment: More interesting: there is a sequence of continuous functions with a continuous pointwise limit such that the convergence is not uniform on any open set. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500399/a-theorem-about-converge-pointwisely-and-uniformly).

Comment: Depending on circumstances Dini's theorem, see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini_theorem, could be of help.